# Swift Parse.com UITableView doesn't reloadData after updating the NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

I have a UITableView that should display Users, it displays for the first time, but does not update when reloadData() is called.

The code initiating the tableView and the reloadData function are as follows:

```
let query = PFQuery(className: UserModel.parseClassName())
    query.whereKey("gender", equalTo: current.sexe)
    query.limit = countPerPage
    query.skip = pageIndex * countPerPage
    query.order(byAscending: "fullname")
    query.findObjectsInBackground(block: {(objects: [PFObject]!, error: Error!) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            for object in objects as! [UserModel]{

                self.userArray.add(object)
            }

            self.serachTable.reloadData()

        } else {
            print("error")

        }
    })
```

Comment: update once in mainthread and check

Comment: Try to update with `datasource` and `delagate` method of the table.

Comment: @ Three Coins how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`reloadData` must be called on main thread. Add `DispatchQueue.main.async` around `reloadData`:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.serachTable.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your data source loads data from `userArray`?

Answer (score 0):

First remove data from your **self.userArray** and then add data like

`self.userArray.append(object)`

after that called reload tableview. before doing this verify your datasource and delegate connected in viewcontroller